# Updating a java.sql.Date into a database using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, eclipse, date, ms-access, prepared-statement

I've been scratching my head for the past few hours wondering what is wrong. I want to edit a Date/Time format on my access database and it'a just keeps on confusing me as to why I cant update it. This is my code and I will explain. . .

This is the Main class where there's a button that says update and when clicked will lead to another class called UpdateBooking_Run()

```
public MainInterface() {
    JButton updateBookings = new JButton("UPDATE");
    updateBookings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            UpdateBooking_Run ub = new UpdateBooking_Run();
            ub.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
```

This is UpdateBooking_Run() without the textboxes only the button inside this class...As you can see from string, I converted the date to java.sql.Date

```
public class UpdateBooking_Run extends JFrame {
   public static java.sql.Date sqldate;
   public UpdateBooking_Run() {
      JButton btnAdd = new JButton("UPDATE");
       btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(yearBookings.getText().trim());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException na) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input year", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            String mu = monthBookings.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String da = dayBookings.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String ye = yearBookings.getText().trim();

            String dat =  ye + "/" + mu + "/" + da ;

            java.util.Date date = null;

            try {
                date = df.parse(dat);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sqldate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

            try {
                UpdateConn_Run uc = new UpdateConn_Run();
                uc.updateDate();
            }
            catch (Exception en) {
                en.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
       });
     }
  }
```

As you can see in the code above, I set sqldate as static mainly because it worked with updating string on my other classes but I just cant seem to update Date. . .

Then this is the connection... Or UpdateConn_Run()

```
public class UpdateConn_Run {
   Connection con;
   Statement st;
   ResultSet rs;
   StringBuffer results;
   String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C://DATABASE//DATA.accdb";   
   PreparedStatement ps;

      public void updateBooking() {
        try {
           int i = 1;
           UpdateBooking_Run ubr = new UpdateBooking_Run();
           MainInterface mi = new MainInterface();

        Date da = UpdateBooking_Run.sqldate;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        //theres actually an uneditable textbox in MainInterface that shows the ID of the selected row
        int id = Integer.parseInt(mi.idstringBookings);
        String sql = "UPDATE bookings SET date ='"+da+"' WHERE ID ='"+id+"'";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();
        con.close();

        if (i == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database has been updated please click Refresh");

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also seem to get the error...

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: data exception: invalid datetime format
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:261)
at interfaceSystem.UpdateConn_Run.updateBooking(UpdateConn_Run.java:109)
at interfaceSystem.UpdateBooking_Run$2.actionPerformed(UpdateBooking_Run.java:284)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But it still confuses me . . .

- It says invalid datetime format so I went ahead and changed the format again and again. Even tried the format in MS Access the problem still persists.
- Tried not putting in the date as static. I just get "null".
- Can someone explain why static is used for updating databases in PreparedStatements? Still confuses me to this day... (Everyone in my class seems to be using it although I have no idea why)

I am sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker so I appreciate it if you have questions regarding grammar...

Comment: i have a program where i use a prepared statement and a date. i generate the date like following `java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date.getTime());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a `PreparedStatement`, you should be using placeholders and your code should be as follow:

```
query = "UPDATE bookings SET date = ? WHERE id = ?";

preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setDate(1, da);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, id);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Because you're including a `Date` object into a `String`, it will be parsed using its `toString()` method, and your statement will look like:

```
"UPDATE bookings SET date = 2000-01-12 WHERE id = 22"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I must read more on PreparedStatement. I was finally able to update my database. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't do Java, but your final SQL for Access must look like this:

```
"UPDATE bookings SET date = #2017/03/21# WHERE ID = '1'";
```

or, if ID is numeric:

```
"UPDATE bookings SET date = #2017/03/21# WHERE ID = 1";
```

Thus, something like:

```
//datestring = da formatted as "2017/03/20"
String sql = "UPDATE bookings SET date =#"+datestring+"# WHERE ID ='"+id+"'";
```